# Checking that a proof is correct.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

{Let $\{E_{n}\}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets of real numbers. Prove that the set $A$ of all those points that belong to infinitely many sets from the sequence $\{E_{n}\}$ is Lebesgue measurable.

**My proof:**
Let $\{E_{n}\}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets of real numbers.Define $A := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: x \in E_{n}$ for infinitely many n$\},$ 
we want to prove that $A$ is measurable.$\

Let $x\in A$, $B_{n}:= \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}E_{k}.$ Then $A\subseteq B_{n}$ for all $n$.Then $A\subseteq \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n}.$ so if $x \in A$ then there is at least one $m \geq n$ such that $x \in E_{m}$ and we can say that:
   $A =  \cap_{m=1}^{\infty} B_{m}$    for $m \geq n.$\
Now, we know that the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets is a $\sigma-$algebra, hence it is closed under countable unions and intersections. And since each $E_{k}$ is Lebesgue measurable, so $A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

**My added part to correct the bold part in the proof:**

I will prove that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \subseteq A$.

Let $x \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n}$, then $x \in  B_{n}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$ But $B_{n} := \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}E_{k},$ then there $\exists k \geq n$ such that $x \in E_{k}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$ then $x \in E_{k}$ for infinitely many $k$. and hence $x \in A.$

Is my proof correct, did I really showed that x belongs to $E_{k}$ for infinitely may $k$?

Thanks!

Comment: Your proof could be clearer. See my answer. You define $B_n$ as the inner unions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set is called $\limsup_{n \to \infty} E_n$ and can be written as

$$\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_n$$ which is evidently measurable (expressible as countable unions and intersections of measurable sets).

$x$ is in the set described iff for every $n$ (intersection!) there is some $k \ge n$ (union!) such that $x \in E_k$. Some thought shows that this means exactly that $\{n: x \in A_n\}$ has no upper bound, so must be infinite.

Comment: but my added part is correct .......correct?

Comment: @hopefully It's not very clear: my argument that the statement implies that a set is unbounded and thus infinite, is cleaner. You just *claim* that $x$ is infinitely many $E_k$ without offering an argument as to why that is.